# Conditions that Fail Fubini's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In general, there are two versions of the Fubini's theorem:

(1) non-negative functions $f$ and $\sigma$-finiteness.
(2) integrable functions $f$ and $\sigma$-finiteness.

Can you elaborate and correct my intuition behind the above pre-conditions?

(1) The reason we look at non-negativity and integrability is associated with the monotone and dominated convergence theorem. Basically, the non-negativity enables us to use the MCT when we pass on the limit inside using the usual machinery starting from the simple functions. Without this, we lose the measurability of the limit of a sequence of measurable functions. The integrability is similar as it is associated with the DCT.

(2) If we don't have the $\sigma$-finiteness of each measure, then it doesn't make sense to define a product measure? There might be an instance where if you look at a slice of a set $E_{\omega_1}$ at $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$, you could have a collection of $\omega_2$ which belongs to $F_2$, but for a $F_1\times F_2$-measurable function $f$, the function slice $f_{\omega_1}$ at $\omega_1$ is no longer $F_2$-measurable. So we don't have a unique measure $P_1\times P_2=P$ that can be used to operationalize the Fubini's theorem.

Please correct and improve the above intuition if there is error.

Comment: Anybody can give me help?